# Access multiple versions of a package in Java

Tags: java, osgi, apache-commons, classloader

We have several applications that use Apache HTTPClient 3 to make HTTP requests. Recently we have also began creating web service clients that use HTTPClient 4 for various reasons. The Apache stance is that "*major releases are not backwards compatible*". While I would love to update all of our projects to use version 4, that's simply not feasible.

So, while my main question is rather general, my particular question is. **How can I use HTTPClient version 3 and 4 in the same application?** In our case an application can be a web, desktop, or command line app.

I have read the [SO question for java-dynamically-load-multiple-versions-of-same-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705720/java-dynamically-load-multiple-versions-of-same-class) which seems semi close but I don't care so much about the dynamic part. In fact I would like the JARs to be shipped with the app (example, WEB-INF/lib for web apps) I also see [OSGi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) mentioned a lot in questions similar to this one but it seems to be overkill or perhaps overly complex (maybe a simple example could prove otherwise).

In the end I want to be able to hand a team a set of jars that they can drop in and it just works independent of their project using HTTP Client 3.

Comment: This is a case where architectural governance would have been a good idea: making a decision either to stick with version 3 or move everything to version 4. Now you have to pay an implementation costs for a patchwork solution, and it will just get worse over time.

Comment: @Anon: No offense but without knowing the situation I wouldn't advice making such a blanket statement. I said "for various reasons" to ward off such comments.

Comment: OSGi at least works (You need to decide if its overkill or not), I don't know of any trivial way to do this other than to have two web servers, one for each version of the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have stated, you can create multiple classloaders and load the two versions in isolation. This part is easy enough.

The problem is, this essentially splits your "class space", and it will still be very hard to refer to v3 from some parts of your application while referring to v4 from other parts of your application. You will have to partition your application *very* carefully... so why not just split it and deliver two applications?

OSGi could be a solution if you are able to factor out functionality into services. But converting a legacy application to OSGi is not something to take on lightly, and it will certainly not be a cheap escape from the trap that you have walked into. I say this as the author of a book on OSGi and a well-known OSGi evangelist. A long-term goal of converting your applications to OSGi **would** bring you great benefits, but will also involve significant up-front costs.

Answer (score 2):

An easy but straightforward solution would be you get the sources for HttpClient3 and HttpClient4, and refactor the package names to something like

**org.apache.commons.httpclient3** for HttpClient3 and **org.apache.commons.httpclient4** for HttpClient4 to avoid collision. Then compile, package, done.

Now it is easy to switch between the two implementations and they don't collide in the classloader.

Comment: While this works for one jar, it creates more issues than it solves.  You might need apache.commons.logging for example, and both versions will be dependent of different versions of commons logging (since they were released at different times).  Now you could repack commons logging in the above manner, but then you have to go back and manually edit all the source code in the repacked http clients to reference correctly.  Soon such a solution becomes a big mess.

Comment: Do they really depend on different versions of commons-logging? The latest one should work fine with both, no?

Comment: Note that the commons-lang people are going this route. Commons Lang 3 will be using the package name org.apache.commons.lang3. If you are going to have incompatible API changes, a new package name is probably not the worst idea.

Comment: Edwin, I don't think its eligible to say that "this creates more issues than it solves" just by guessing so. I don't think there will be trouble if you use the latest version of commons logging. I used many apache projects that depended on different jcl versions, and using the latest jcl never lead to problems. However, you can use slf4j with its jcl-over-slf4j.jar to remove jcl completely and bridge everything over slf4j to get jcl version conflicts out of the way. There is no need to rafactor jcl.

Comment: If a product works with the latest version, it's not a problem.  The issues come when dealing with dependencies where the "older" version of a doubly packed item doesn't work with the "newer" release of the down stream dependency.  "Does this happen often?" isn't really the question, as if it happens once it puts the packaging scheme in jeopardy.  The suggestion is not a bad way of doing things, but it has it's risks; which was all I was trying to point out.

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple class loaders, one for each HTTP Client you wish to embrace.

The simplest way is to extend URLClassLoader and hack it to hardcode the classpath for each version separately.  Then you just need to make sure the rest of the code knows which version of the HTTP client to use (and accesses the correct classloader to get to it).

Comment: How would this work for a webapp where the JARs have to shipped with the WARs?

Comment: You ship all versions of each library referenced, but put them somewhere other than web-inf/lib.  Your custom class loader looks in the "somewhere other" location.  This prevents the war container from referencing them directly.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use separate class loaders for v3 and v4. Put v3 and v4 jars to separate folders beyond your application classpath. Use URLClassLoadedr to load each one of the versions. The URL that you pass to each one of class loaders should contain URL to specific version of HTTP client.

But may I give you an advice? Check first that you really need all these before you are starting. That is right that the versions could be incompatible. But there is a huge chance that they are.

Comment: I think you mean "huge chance they are *not*" I know HTTP Client v3 and V4 don't play well together.